# Download a file from a database using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-5

Long story short, I've saved .docx files to my database using rails, but I'm having a lot of trouble retrieving the files saved in the database and downloading them.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you want to download that file? using rails ? like on click on that file you want to download by browser in your local system? am i right?

Comment: That's  exactly what I'm looking for - is it not possible with rails?

Comment: sure here i m giving an example.

Comment: are you using paperclip or carrierwave ? which gem you are using to save file?

Answer (score 1):

1- create a action to download ex -

suppose your model name is `MyModel` and your column name is `file` where you saving the .docx file

```
  def download
    object = MyModel.find(params[:id])
    send_file object.file.path(:original), :disposition => 'download'
  end
```

2- create a routes for this action

```
 get 'download/:id', to: 'my_controllers#download', as: :download_my_file
```

3- and you can use this routes in view page where you want to give option to download: -

```
<%=link_to 'download', download_my_file_path(id: my_model_id)%>
```

hope i'm clear with my example, let me know for further guidance

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - I'm just a little confused on the last line, "download_my_file_path(id: my_model_id)". I'm not sure what download_my_file_path means (or what I should change it to).

Comment: @Hychet after adding 2 step, that routes line `as: :downlaod_my_file` when you will check `rake routes` at console you will get routes . and to use this routes we use it as `downlaod_my_file_path` and in this path we are sending id of model where file is alredy saved to fetch that file. am i clear. you can change the routes according to you. and it only routes sentence that you generally use. am i clear?

Comment: @Hychet feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. :)